# Unexpected output in presence of static keyword

Tags: c, static

Why is the following programm giving me  an unexpected output.

```
    static int x[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    int i;
    for (i = 2; i < 6;++i)
      {

         x[x[i]] = x[i];
      }
        for (i = 0; i < 8;++i)
           {

             printf("%d",x[i]);


           }

      }
```

I expect it to be 1 ,2 3,4,5,6,7,8 but the compiler says:1,2,3,3,5,6,7,8.
Btw what is the impact of `static` on an array performance?

Comment: Step through the code in a debugger, keeping an eye on the variables ad especially what `x[i]` is. And remember that index `3` is the *fourth* entry in the array.

Comment: And to avoid confusion in future code, when you're having nested loops, then don't use the same loop variable.

Comment: That is the exact expected output from your program, regardless of `static`, it has not effect.

Comment: You are aware that the statement in the outer `for` loop is only executed once?

Comment: why do you expect `,` between the numbers? I think the output of the program is `12335678`.

Comment: downvoted  for.............?

Answer (score 1):

```
x[x[i]] = x[i];

i =2;

x[2] = 3;

x[3] = x[2];

x[3] = 3;
```

So you see this output.You are incrementing `i` in the inner loop so you will see the outer loop executing only once.

Answer (score 0):

You are writing x[x[i]] = x[i] like this its wrong

because at starting i=2 means it refer to x[2]=3

So that here x[x[i]] means x[3] you are replacing with x[2] thats why  3 is coming two time

and 4 is replaced by 3.

Correct:

x[x[i-1]] = x[i]

now try....